# Dentro de un ActionPerformed quiero hacer dos cosas. No obstante, quiero que haya una pausa entre ambas

Tags: java-swing

El evento del ActionPerformed termina cuando las sentencias que haya dentro del evento terminan de ejecutarse. Por tanto, me interesa llamar a la segunda sentencia de código en otro evento que se ejecute después del ActionPerformed. Ej "CuandoTermineActionPerformed".

Mi objetivo es, al hacer click sobre un botón, que tiene un determinado color, quitarle su icono y posteriormente, tras la espera, evaluar si hay algún otro botón del mismo color o no. Para así volver a ponerle el icono o eliminar dicha pareja de botones.

Llamar a "evaluarEleccion()" en el ActionPerformed genera el problema de no poder ver el color del segundo botón, ya sea acertado o no.

Necesito una alternativa para llamar a "evaluarEleccion()" en otro evento.

Muchas gracias.

Código: https://pastebin.com/6q07Y3Ds

Comment: Buenas, Manuel, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Has echado un ojo a [tour] y [ask]? ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta para incluir tu código como texto formateado de forma que tengamos un [mcve]?